# How to colorize similar color regions like magic wand tool?

Tags: imagemagick, magickwand

Please help on this. I´d like to isolate areas to find some coordinates based on colors to crop regions of interest later. Specifically,
(1st) I want to colorize in black the similar gray regions and
(2nd) the "1 pixel" height lines between, in order that black regions after the step 1 and 2 be connected like in output shown below.

When I analyse the image below with an image editor like Paint.net and select `magic wand` tool, locating it in position (x=395, y=190) with a tolerance of 32%, the similar gray regions are selected.Then I can manually colorize in black the selected area.

**Magick Wand tool selecting similar grays with 32% of tolerance in Paint.net**

[image]

I found the `magicwand` method in [Fred´s scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/magicwand/index.php) and try to send the example with logo2.png but says command not found, then I wasn´t able to try with my input image.

I'm running IM in cygwin under Windows.

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-61 Q16 x86_64 2023-05-13 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig fpx freetype gslib gvc heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raqm raw rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib



$ magicwand 160,200 -t 25 -f image -r inside -m edge -c red logo2.png logo2_out.png
-bash: magicwand: command not found
```

**Original input image.**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick with flood fill.  (Alternate, use -fuzz XX% -fill black -opaque "rgb(XX,XX,XX)" for the gray XX value you want for middle gray in the image).  Pick a coordinate at the mid gray color (not too dark gray and not too light gray). Adjust the fuzz value as needed.

Input:

[image]

```
magick picture2.png -alpha off -fuzz 12% -fill black -draw "color 340,125 floodfill" -alpha off x.png
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wooww. Excelent! I understand about what you say of grays and why it works for continuos regions with similar grays, but how was possible to capture the horizontal 1 height pixel lines of color #EEEEE? since the big squares have soft blue vertical borders.

Comment: It filled the vertical border enough to get to the horizontal lines. It was very sensitive to the fuzz value. 10 and 15 were not good. But 12 seemed to work.

Comment: Nice. Last question.  If I would like to make more changes to the image can I concatenate more commands? For example convert in white the green, blues, etc?

Comment: For each color region, you would have to either flood fill or better for each color use -fuzz XX% -fill white -opaque "rgb(XX,YY,ZZ)". Those could be just chained in the same command line to the above answer.